# Screen cast/screen share/remote desktop controk SDK for .NET

Tags: .net, sdk

I am working on a project needs a screen cast/screen share/remote desktop control feature. The software should be able to broadcast the screen of one PC to at least 16 other PCs in real-time and the administrator can monitor and control activities at any PC in real-time also. Is there any SDK (free or commercial) available?

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, but the Terminals project (http://terminals.codeplex.com/) is open source and does RDP as well as a number of different remote connection stuff.  You might get some hints reading the source...

Comment: I'm actually looking something similar to Radmin or VNC. I cannot use RDP because I need to broadcast the screen to multiple PCs at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer but here is an article about remote desktop in .Net: [Palantir - Remote Desktop Manager](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Palantir.aspx)

What about [VncSharp](http://cdot.senecac.on.ca/projects/vncsharp/) or [.NET VNC Viewer](http://dotnetvnc.sourceforge.net/) ?

Comment: I'm actually looking something similar to Radmin or VNC. I cannot use RDP because I need to broadcast the screen to multiple PCs at once.

Comment: VncSharp looks promising. I will try to look into it. Thanks. Any reference to the vnc server part?

Answer (score 0):

I have information that not very expensive commercial VNC SDK solution are provided by abtoVNC [here](http://remote-screen.com/).  They sell SDK and sources of VNC protocol based custom remote desktop solutions for Windows, Android and iOS